# How to make IntelliJ IDEA respect pre-commit-msg hook

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pre-commit-hook

I would like to prefill the commit message depending on the branch name I am currently on.
I have this working with a `pre-commit-msg` hook from the command line but when commiting from IDEA there is no effect. The commit msg is prepopulated by the last commit msg (I think?).
Is there a way to get this working?

Edit: I just found out that the hook is working when I reword a commit message in IDEA. But that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately.
Commit dialog is shown before any git commit operations are called, that is why the hook is never executed.

Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114680

Maybe a plugin like this may help you to achieve your goal:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9278-pre-commit-hook-plugin

Comment: Thank you as the issue has been opened 6 years ago I guess chances are rather slim to get fixed. I'll try to see what the plugin can do.